# android-maven-plugin works great why bother migrating to gradle? (for Android projects)

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle, android-maven-plugin

**gradle** seems to be the heat of the moment, but which real benefits would a project take by using **[gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)** instead of **[android-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/)** for Android projects?

The reasons listed on the site http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide did not convince me.

Note: my preferred IDE is Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

The Gradle based toolchain is/will be supported by Google while Maven plugin will have to play catch up game. While the reasons may not convince you they are important for many developers. The more complex application the more chances you will see the point of multi-APKs and flavors and other things.

BTW: you are asking in a heavily opinionated way which makes your question candidate to be put on hold.